# [django]How to get topics user replied?

Tags: django, django-models, comments

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body  = models.TextField(_('body'), max_length=TEXT_MAX_LENGTH)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topic_user', editable=False)
    ...
```

I use 'django.contrib.comments' to reply a topic. How to get topics I replied(just know my user id)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
Topic.objects.filter(pk__in=[comment.content_object.pk for comment in Comment.objects.filter(user__exact = request.user)])
```

Comment: This works, but it isn't terribly efficient. Something like `Topic.objects.filter(comments__user__exact=request.user)` (note the double underscores) will work better. Django's query language can do a lot! (My code example won't work out of the box, as your model in the question isn't complete, btw)